# malloc can't create space for struct in queue

Tags: c, struct, queue, malloc

I tried to create a queue which contains 2 int values. The problem happens in insert function. When i try to allocate memory for head->front->next program halts. The error happens only in else part in insert function.

```
struct Patient{
   int national_id;
   int condition;
};

struct Node{
   struct Patient *info;
   struct Node *next;
};

struct Queue{
   int total;
   struct Node *rear;
   struct Node *front;
   int insert_number;
};

void insert (struct Queue *head, int natid, int cond);
void pop_min(struct Queue *head);
struct Queue *create_queue(void);
void destroy_queue(struct Queue *head);
void read_file(struct Queue *head);
void print_natid(struct Node *node);
void pop_all_elements(struct Queue *head);

void main(){
   struct Queue *head;

   head=create_queue();
   read_file(head);
   pop_all_elements(head);
   destroy_queue(head);
}

struct Queue *create_queue(void){

   struct Queue *head =(struct Queue*) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
   head->total=0;
   head->insert_number=0;
   return head;

}

void print_natid(struct Node *node){
   printf("%d ",node->info->national_id);
}


void insert (struct Queue *head,int natid, int cond){

   if(head->total==0){
      head->front=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      head->front->info->national_id=natid;
      head->front->info->condition=cond;
      head->rear=head->front;
   }
   else{

      head->front->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      head->front->next->info->national_id=natid;
      head->front->next->info->condition=cond;
      head->front=head->front->next;
   }


   head->insert_number++;
   head->total++;

   if(head->insert_number==3){
      pop_min(head);
      head->insert_number=0;
   }

   print_natid(head->rear);

}

void pop_min(struct Queue *head){

   printf("%d ",head->rear->info->national_id);

   struct Node *temp=head->rear;
   head->rear=head->rear->next;

   free(head->rear);
   free(temp);
}

void destroy_queue(struct Queue *head){
   free(head);
}

void pop_all_elements(struct Queue *head){
   struct Node *temp;

   while(head->rear!=head->front){
      print_natid(head->rear);
      temp=head->rear;
      free(temp);
      head->rear=head->rear->next;
   }

   print_natid(head->rear);
   free(head->rear);

}

void read_file(struct Queue *head){
   FILE *fp;
   int natid;
   int cond;
   fp=fopen("patients.txt","r");

   while (fscanf(fp,"%d %d", &natid, &cond) ==2)
      insert(head,natid,cond);

   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `total` represent?

Comment: total number of elements.

Comment: So you are continously connecting new element to the same head. You should be either adding to the last element of the queue, not the head or traverse the list starting from the head.

Comment: I add elements from head->front. rear always holds the oldest element in the queue. Head is created for once. Actually  i did not understand what i meant.

Comment: You are adding elements in the same place over and over. Analyze what your code is doing.

Comment: It is the exact purpose of queue. You add elements to queue from front. rear of head holds oldest element, front holds newest element, if you want  to add new element you should allocate memory from front and bind the second newest element to newest element that is just created.

Comment: Your naming is weird.  Normally, the position at which newly enqueued objects are placed is called the "back" (or "rear" or "tail" or even "end") of the queue, and the position containing the element that will be dequeued next is called the "front" (or "head").  It's just like a queue ("line", for Americans) at the coffee shop.  Furthermore, the term "pop" is pretty closely associated with stacks, so its use with queues is jarring.

Comment: I know that. I realized that fault when i finished the work. I will handle it when i correct all errors. By the way, if we focus on the problem, why c doesn't allocate memory for head->front->next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code:

**Problem 1**

In `insert()`, you haven't allocated memory for the `info` of the newly allocated `Node` before setting values on it.

You are also not setting the `next` of the newly constructed node in `insert`. `rear->next` remains uninitialized. If you access that pointer later, you will run into undefined behavior.

I would change the following block of code to fix the above problems as well as reduce duplicate code.

Your code:

```
if(head->total==0){
   head->front=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   head->front->info->national_id=natid;
   head->front->info->condition=cond;
   head->rear=head->front;
}
else{

   head->front->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   head->front->next->info->national_id=natid;
   head->front->next->info->condition=cond;
   head->front=head->front->next;
}
```

My suggestion:

```
struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
node->next = NULL;
node->info = malloc(sizeof(struct Patient));
node->info->national_id=natid;
node->info->condition=cond;

if(head->total==0){
   head->front = node;
   head->rear = node;
}
else{
   head->front->next = node;
   head->front = node;
}
```

**Problem 2**

You have an additional call to `free` in `pop_min`.

```
// This is wrong.
// Not only do you not need this but also it causes
// problems later when you try to use head->rear.
free(head->rear);
```

**Problem 3**

The following lines in `pop_all_elements` are a problem.

```
  temp=head->rear;
  free(temp);

  // PROBLEM
  // Here you are trying to access memory that just got free'd in
  // previous line.
  head->rear=head->rear->next;
```

You need to swap the last two lines. Use:

```
  temp=head->rear;
  head->rear=head->rear->next;
  free(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add in the else part-

```
(head->front->next).info=(struct Patient *)malloc(sizeof(struct Patient));
```

Comment: It is actually missing from both parts, plus you are creating a loop in then else part.

Comment: I added that part but didn't help. Because it deosn't allocate memory for head->front->next the problem begins from there. Also in Node struct there is a pointer of struct Patient also. If i allocate ememory for node the space for Patient will be automaticly created i guess.

Comment: as _chqrlie_ said it is missing from the if part also, your memory allocation is not correct. You have to assign memory the same way @Y.E.S.

Comment: The head->front->next isn't created. If i will be able to create head->front->next i will try what you said. But the main problem is about memory allocation for head->fron->next it gives error.

Comment: It will be better if you create a temp node like struct node *temp, then assigning all the values to temp you add it to the rear or front you like. This will reduce your complexity @Y.E.S.

Comment: If i solve he memory allocation problem i will do what you suggested. But problem is different now. C doesn't allocate memory for head->front->next and why?

Answer (score 1):

> When i try to allocate memory for head->front->next program halts. The error happens only in else part in insert function.

If in fact the error happens inside `malloc()` then it's symptomatic of a memory corruption issue whose true locus is probably elsewhere.  One candidate would be this incorrect code from `pop_all_elements()`:

```
while(head->rear!=head->front){
    print_natid(head->rear);
    temp=head->rear;
    free(temp);
    head->rear=head->rear->next;
}
```

It dereferences a pointer to freed memory when it evaluates `head->rear->next`.  Fix that by moving `free(temp)` to the end of the loop body.

Another candidate is `pop_min()`:

```
   struct Node *temp=head->rear;
   head->rear=head->rear->next;

   free(head->rear);
   free(temp);
```

Observe that you free not only the old `rear`, but also the **new** `rear`, leaving `head->rear` an invalid pointer (which you quite likely try to free again later if the program continues much past that).  That function is sometimes called by `insert()`, so it could cause problems for repeated calls to `insert()` such as are performed by function `read_file()`.

Other candidates include this code that appears in both branches of your insert function:

```
    head->front->info->national_id=natid;
    head->front->info->condition=cond;
```

In neither case do you assign a value to `head->front->info`, so those two assignments produce undefined behavior, which absolutely could manifest as memory corruption.  You could consider fixing that by changing the type of `Node.info` from `struct Patient *` to `struct Patient` (with corresponding changes elsewhere); among other things, that would also relieve you of any need to *free* those dynamically allocated `Patient`s when you dequeue a node.

Another possibility, however, is that `malloc()` works fine, but `head->front` is a null or invalid pointer, so that assigning to `head->front->next` produces undefined behavior (manifesting as a memory access violation and concomitant halt).  I'm not quite seeing how that would come about, but given that you have several pointer-related problems, it is conceivable.

While I'm at it, I observe that your measures apparently aimed at limiting the queue to two elements are grossly ineffective.  This code ...

```
head->insert_number++;
head->total++;

if(head->insert_number==3){
    pop_min(head);
    head->insert_number=0;
}
```

... will dequeue one element for every three enqueued, but if four or more are enqueued before any are (otherwise) dequeued then afterward the queue will contain more than two elements.  Moreover, you do not update either `insert_number` or `total` when you dequeue elements, so these contain information only about how many elements were ever inserted.  Note especially that `insert()` depends on `total` to determine whether the queue is empty, and this test will produce wrong results if the queue is emptied after any elements are enqueued.